slither error: "No such file or directory: 'out/build-info'"
I am attempting to run this slither command:
slither . --solc-remaps @openzeppelin/contracts/=lib/openzeppelin-contracts/contracts/

And I'm running into the following error:
'forge clean' running (wd: /home/ziion/Desktop/Github Repo's To Audit/fund-distribution-contracts)
'forge build --build-info --force' running

Missing dependencies found. Installing now...

Updating dependencies in "/home/ziion/Desktop/Github Repo\'s To Audit/fund-distribution-contracts/lib"

Your project has missing dependencies that could not be installed.
Error: 
Failed to resolve file: "/home/ziion/Desktop/Github Repo's To Audit/fund-distribution-contracts/lib/forge-std/src/Script.sol": No such file or directory (os error 2).
 Check configured remappings..
    --> "/home/ziion/Desktop/Github Repo\'s To Audit/fund-distribution-contracts/script/FeeRouterDeployer/NovaToDAOTreasury/eth-deploy.s.sol"
        "forge-std/Script.sol"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ziion/.local/pipx/venvs/slither-analyzer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 837, in main_impl
    ) = process_all(filename, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/ziion/.local/pipx/venvs/slither-analyzer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 90, in process_all
    compilations = compile_all(target, **vars(args))
  File "/home/ziion/.local/pipx/venvs/slither-analyzer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 643, in compile_all
    compilations.append(CryticCompile(target, **kwargs))
  File "/home/ziion/.local/pipx/venvs/slither-analyzer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 131, in __init__
    self._compile(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ziion/.local/pipx/venvs/slither-analyzer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 553, in _compile
    self._platform.compile(self, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ziion/.local/pipx/venvs/slither-analyzer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/crytic_compile/platform/foundry.py", line 90, in compile
    hardhat_like_parsing(crytic_compile, self._target, build_directory, self._target)
  File "/home/ziion/.local/pipx/venvs/slither-analyzer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/crytic_compile/platform/hardhat.py", line 49, in hardhat_like_parsing
    os.listdir(build_directory), key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(Path(build_directory, x))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'out/build-info'
ERROR:root:Error in .
ERROR:root:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ziion/.local/pipx/venvs/slither-analyzer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 837, in main_impl
    ) = process_all(filename, args, detector_classes, printer_classes)
  File "/home/ziion/.local/pipx/venvs/slither-analyzer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/slither/__main__.py", line 90, in process_all
    compilations = compile_all(target, **vars(args))
  File "/home/ziion/.local/pipx/venvs/slither-analyzer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 643, in compile_all
    compilations.append(CryticCompile(target, **kwargs))
  File "/home/ziion/.local/pipx/venvs/slither-analyzer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 131, in __init__
    self._compile(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ziion/.local/pipx/venvs/slither-analyzer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/crytic_compile/crytic_compile.py", line 553, in _compile
    self._platform.compile(self, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ziion/.local/pipx/venvs/slither-analyzer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/crytic_compile/platform/foundry.py", line 90, in compile
    hardhat_like_parsing(crytic_compile, self._target, build_directory, self._target)
  File "/home/ziion/.local/pipx/venvs/slither-analyzer/lib/python3.9/site-packages/crytic_compile/platform/hardhat.py", line 49, in hardhat_like_parsing
    os.listdir(build_directory), key=lambda x: os.path.getmtime(Path(build_directory, x))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'out/build-info'

How do I get past this?
